# Rollback additions / removals to DBSets of the DbContext using a transaction in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

A general pattern for me in a project using Entity Framework 6 is to

1. Create new entities for addition
2. Add the entities to the relevant `DBSet` of the `DbContext`
3. Set the properties of these objects
4. Call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Here is some pseudo-code for what I mean:

```
    // Psuedo code to illustrate process. 
    void AddProcess()
    {

        var modelsToAdd = GetModelsToAdd();

        try
        {
            _context.Models.AddRange(modelsToAdd);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            // If we get here all is good.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _context.RemoveRange(modelsToAdd);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //....
        }
    }
```

I am aware the `SaveChanges()` method internally creates its own `Transaction`, so that if there is an exception during the save this will be rolled back. However, what I want is for the added entities in (2) to be removed from the `DbSet` if an error occurs during `SaveChanges()`. Basically, as if the 'Add' process had never taken place.

As you can see, at the moment I am caching a list of the models involved, and then removing them if an exception happens.

What I would like to know is there a better way to do this with Transactions automatically doing the work for me? So, can the internal `Transaction` rollback of `SaveChanges()` also rollback any additions to the `DbSet`'s? Or can other Transactions be used?

What is the best / preferred way to achieve what I am looking for? I'm fairly new to EF, so this might be something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1 from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-undo-the-changes-in-00aed3c4 is typically enough for most implementations where you want to roll-back changes in the DbContext without dropping and re-instantiating a Context. Generally the request would have failed and the call would have ended so the DbContext scope should end until a retry is attempted in a new request.

I'd only be looking at rolling back a DbContext if there was a really good reason for an immediate retry/alternate action. Wanting to roll back DbSets in the case of a SaveChanges failure is usually an indicator that a DbContext that is being kept alive too long.

Important things like logging that need to be saved in the case of a failure should use a dedicated DbContext so that their updates are not hindered by a failed SaveChanges on the application's DbContext.

Comment: Hi Steve, really sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your help. I adopted the approach contained in the link you kindly provided.